# Adding another view to a view based application

Tags: iphone, multiview

I'm developing an iphone apllication that stores some data into a database. That is working fine. But now i have a problem when i want to show the data. Because to show the data i need to design another view. But i'm facing problem when i try to add another view.Is it possible to have multiple view in a view-based application,cause my application is a view-based application? If yes then how to do that? Please help me

Thanks in advance
Joy

Answer (score 5, accepted):

yes. In principle you create your new view [alloc/ init], then display it.

Normally you would display it by pushing it onto the navigation controller stack.

`[self.navigationController pushViewController:newViewController animated:YES];`

If you don't have a navigation controller, you either need to create one (your best bet might be to use xcode to make a navigation based application and take a look at how its put together).

If you just want to simply display a second view controller, then you can display that as a modal view controller: alloc/init your second view controller then display it with

`[self presetModalViewController:newViewContoller animated:YES];`

Finally you could do a front view/ flipside view. Take a look at the utility application template in xcode.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible to use multiple views. You can manually add them to the window by using `addSubView`.

You can also use a view controller like a UINavigationController or a UITabBarController.

It depends on how you want to display the views and how the user can switch between them.